# how to avoid the selection using ctrl + shift and clicking in a Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, listselectionlistener

we are using a JTable where we allow multi selection only when some datas are same otherwise not allowed to Multi-select. This is achieved by overriding ChangeSelection method of Jtable.

But if ctrl+shift & clicking in this table, it selects all the elements between those to selection even the data doesn't matches because ChangeSelection method is not triggered when user has clicked with pressing Ctrl+Shift.

Can someone give idea to how we can avoid this? Is this a requirement of JTable to avoid ctrl+shift selection?

we also have ListSelectionListener to that table and overridden ValueChanged to save the selected rows.